# What can an employer see on your profile?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy

My friend has done something nasty with his account and he told me that the moderators have written in his account reference.

What can employers see from an account? Is it just the normal stuff that any stranger would see in my account or can they see a little more? I'm asking because of the integration between Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Careers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Employers cannot see anything more than is visible to other users.

No extra information is visible to companies using Careers, they can only see what you put into your Careers profile.

Moderator messages are entirely private, and are never shared with anyone, and certainly not with employers or other Careers users.

Comment: .... but if the employer is a moderator or has a moderator within its midst... Privacy is now a days only an illusion. By the way, let me be one of the first to prematurely congratulate you as I'm sure that you've got the election in the bag.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: moderators are bound by a [moderator agreement](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) that prohibits them from using that information for anything other than their moderator duties. Of course this won't prevent them from not hiring you if they feel you are not the right sort of person for a job.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: but how often do you think the 15 current moderators of Stack Overflow are in a position to hire someone?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't know. I guess I'm just feeling down from our surveillance society and was just venting.

Comment: I should also note that SE logs all access by moderators to private information, so that they can trace back any public leak or misuse of that information. The only people such private information might influence would be SE, but even then you'd have to act in a persistently abusive way for that to matter. If you made a mistake once and learned from it, I doubt that would at all prevent you from getting a job there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: as Brad points out, it is the moderators that are being surveilled here!

Comment: Note that he's probably talking about the account suspension message.  It is visible for a while.

Comment: @HansPassant: perhaps, but they were asking about private info vs. public: *Is it just the normal stuff that any stranger would see*.

Comment: @BradLarson No one will look on those logs until they know a that was a leak,but moderator could sell that info to the companies,and no one will know about it.I live in a country where if someone it is in a good position,it is corrupt ,so thats way I'm saying this

Comment: Can moderators see personal messages by other moderators?

Comment: @Bergi: yes, because moderators need to be able to pick up where other moderators left off.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's what I guessed, I just wondered about the wording "*entirely private, and are never shared with anyone*"

Comment: @Bergi: right, entirely private to the site; moderators and employees with database access can see just about everything on the site, everywhere, but are bound by the privacy agreement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait a sec,employees can see all the info of my account,more that even I can see ? And were's that privacy agreement?

Comment: @Den the privacy policy is linked from the footer: http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy. Everything is stored in a database so those with access to the database can see everything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So who has access to the database?

Comment: @Den: I don't know, a subset of employees at Stack Exchange. This is their site, after all.

Comment: So if just some SE employees ,then it is okay

Comment: @den Only people in a position of needing access have access.